# How to throw an exception up to the caller, rather than handle it, using RxJava 1.x?

Tags: java, rx-java, couchbase

I have a method using RxJava that calls the jackson object mapper to deserialize a json object into a java object (POJO). The readValue method throws an IOException that must be handled or thrown to the caller of my method. I should not handle it here but rather let my caller handle it. How can I do this in RxJava? Normally it would just need `throws IOException` added to my method signature.

Here is my code:

```
public Observable<T> findByIdAsync(String id) throws IOException {
    return datasource
            .getBucket()
            .async()
            .get(String.valueOf(id), RawJsonDocument.class)
            .map(json -> objectMapper.readValue(json.content(), getType()));
}
```

`objectMapper.readValue(json.content(), getType())` throws `IOException` so it has to either be caught or thrown.

Comment: If the caller does not implement the `onError` and if an exception is thrown, you should be getting `OnErrorNotImplementedException` and if implemented, it gets handled in the `onError` block. Having a `throws` is the not the way we implement with RxJava.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap your `readValue` method into `Observable` using `fromCallable`:

> Returns an Observable that, when an observer subscribes to it, invokes a function you specify and then emits the value returned from that function.

```
.flatMap(json -> Observable.fromCallable(() -> 
                      objectMapper.readValue(json.content(), getType())))
```

Any `Exception` that thrown in `Callable` will interrupt the stream and `Subscriber's` `onError` callback will be triggered (if not handled somewhere in the stream).